# How to join tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables as below:

```
users
 -id (primary key, AUTO_INCREMENT)
 -username (varchar)
 -password (varchar)

users_messages
 -id (primary key, AUTO_INCREMENT)
 -message (text)
 -fk sender_id (int)
 -fk receiver_id(int) 
 -sent_date(datetime)
 -is_read(tinyint)
```

Both foreign keys in users_messages references same table i.e users
I want to write a sql query to get output as below:

```
Message                Sender            Receiver
Message 1 testing      john              sonam
Message 2 testing      meena             shenaz
```

How can i do this? I need to fetch all the messages from users_messages table with sender_id and receiver_id replaced by username column in users table

Edit
Solution:

```
SELECT m.id, m.message, s.username, r.username FROM users_messages m 
INNER JOIN users s ON m.sender_id = s.id
INNER JOIN users r ON m.receiver_id = r.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT m.id, m.message, s.username, r.username
FROM users_messages m 
INNER JOIN users s ON m.sender_id = s.id
INNER JOIN users r ON m.receiver_id = s.id
```